# R ggplot2 facet plot with errorbars: to aes or not aes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a faceted plot of some data with errorbars, where some points have extremely large error bars.

I would like the error bars to just go off the top and bottom of the plot, so I can see what is going on with the values.

I've constructed a toy data set which does what I want, but if I try the same thing with my real data, it breaks; see below. I can't use `facetscales` as that would chop off the error bars that I want to keep; is there an equivalent `facetcoord`?

What am I doing wrong?

```r
library(tidyverse)

#I have some data
x <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
y <- c(11,19,32,38,0.9,2.1,3.1,3.9)
e <- c(3,4,5000,6,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9) #there is a very big value for an error
s <- c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b")
c <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)

tmp <- data.frame(x,y,e,c,s)

#this graph behaves badly, and zooms out to fit the error bar
tmp %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, colour = c)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y - e, ymax = y + e)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(s~ ., scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

```r
#this graph behaves nicely, and doesn't zoom out to fit the error bar
tmp %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, colour = c)) +
  geom_errorbar(ymin = y - e, ymax = y + e) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(s~ ., scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

```r
#But I can't reproduce it with my data!
x2 <- c(0.08364426,0.08363952,0.08367921,0.08358154,0.08357701,0.08360981,0.08363157)
y2 <- c( 0.05267045,0.25550847,54.15868910,56.48984476,59.08971159,0.38898624,0.35820836)
e2 <- c(1.813606e+01,2.115511e-01,5.082708e-02,1.652763e-02,4.866692e-02,6.053884e-04,4.426893e-04)
s2 <- c("a","a","e","e","e","a","a")
c2 <- c(2.245513,2.916980,3.670246,4.281033,5.290035,5.634477,5.935507)

tmp2 <- data.frame(x=x2,y=y2,e=e2,c=c2,s=s2)

#this breaks!
tmp2 %>%   
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = c)) +
  geom_errorbar(ymin = y-e, ymax = y+e)+
  geom_point()  +
  facet_grid(s~ ., scales = "free_y")
```

```r
#Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (7): ymin and ymax
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: When you introduce facets it gets a lot harder to *not* use `aes`, because there's nothing to indicate which `y` and `e` value goes with which `facet` when they're just vectors. It's also tricky to manually set  axis limits for different facets. Ideally there is a way to tell `ggplot` to ignore the `geom_errorbar` layer when setting axis limits, but I don't know that there is. Your best bet may be to not use faceting, stick two plots together, and use `coord_cartesian` to set the limits.

Comment: If you don't put it into the `aes()` statement, the layer doesn't know to lookup the value in the data.frame provided, but searches the global environment instead. To fix your last example, try `geom_errorbar(ymin = y2-e2, ymax = y2+e2)`.

Comment: but why does my toy example work, but not my real? I really don't want to have to stitch plots together, as then I'd have inconsistent styling in my final document.

Comment: @teunbrand thanks for that. I think that is correct. I'll explore that option.  Thanks